# Line of Curvature/geodesic is a plane

Tags: differential-geometry

Let me preface this question with: I have read the related and almost exact questions previously posted. Due to lack of points I cannot comment additional questions on those posts. I have also made many attempts to complete this and still need help. I did not take the prereq to this course so I may be missing something in the background.

Question: Prove that if a line of curvature is a geodesic, then it is a plane curve.

I understand that geodesic curvature is 0 and that the line of curvature is a principle tangent vector. I also understand that torsion must be 0. I have attempted to use frenet formulas and looked at using Rodrigues Theorem but I have not gotten anywhere.

I am asking for direction and possibly steps on how to do this. I greatly appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: If the geodesic curvature is $0$, what does this tell you about the relation between the principal normal of the curve and the surface normal? Now use (a) the tangent vector is a principal direction and (b) the Frenet equations.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this question, but I'm missing something. How would I use the fact the the tangent vector is a principal direction in this question?

Comment: @MateusRocha If you differentiate along the curve, $\mathbf n'(s) = \lambda(s)\mathbf T(s)$ if the curve is a line of curvature. Perhaps the crucial thing you're missing is the first part of the hint? How are $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf N$ related?

Comment: I now that **n** and **N** are parallels, since $C$ is geodesic. So, you used Olinde Rodrigues, and get that **N'** and **T** are parallel. To prove that $C$ is planar, I need to prove that $\tau=0$. I looked at the Frenet equations, and I didn't find a way to use these facts.

Comment: @MateusRocha Really? What is the equation for $\mathbf N'$?

Comment: I typed that and saw it, sorry, hehehe.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I know its super late but I couldn't complete that from your hints. Like equating $\mathbf{t'}=\mathbf{\kappa n}$ and $\mathbf{t'}=\mathbf{\kappa_n N+\kappa_g u}$ we get, $\mathbf{n=N}$. And from Frenet formula we know $\mathbb{n}'=-\kappa \mathbf t+\tau \mathbf b$. From here I didn't see how to conclude $\tau=0$, @TedShifrin

Comment: @N00BMaster You have $\mathbf n = \pm\mathbf N$, actually. You have not yet used the fact that $\mathbf t$ is a principal direction.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting what it mean by, *$t$ is a principal direction*? And how does it reflect the frenet formula @TedShifrin

Comment: @N00BMaster What is the definition of a line of curvature? You need to use this.

Comment: *"A line of curvature is a curve on a surface whose tangent at every point is aligned along a principal curvature direction"*, in that case I only know that $F=0$. Still this information is far away from getting torsion, @TedShifrin

Comment: @N00BMaster Go learn your definitions completely.  You just finished telling me you don’t know what a principal direction is, and yet here it is in the crucial definition. Go work on it.